# not able to find solution, trying to register reducer compilation err...type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'Actions'

Tags: angular, ngrx

```
tutorial.actions.ts

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
    import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'
    import { Tutorial } from './../models/tutorial.model'
    
    export const ADD_TUTORIAL       = '[TUTORIAL] Add'
    export const REMOVE_TUTORIAL    = '[TUTORIAL] Remove'
    
    
    export class AddTutorial implements Action {
        readonly type = ADD_TUTORIAL
    
        constructor(public payload: Tutorial) {}
    }
    
    export class RemoveTutorial implements Action {
        readonly type = REMOVE_TUTORIAL
    
        constructor(public payload: number) {}
    }
    // Section 4
    export type Actions = AddTutorial | RemoveTutorial



import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'
import { Tutorial } from './../models/tutorial.model'
import * as TutorialActions from './../actions/tutorial.actions'

// Section 1
const initialState: Tutorial = {
    name: 'Initial Tutorial',
    url: 'http://google.com'
}

// Section 2
export function reducer(state: Tutorial[] = [initialState], action: TutorialActions.Actions) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case TutorialActions.ADD_TUTORIAL:
            return [...state, action.payload];
        
        // Add this case:
        case TutorialActions.REMOVE_TUTORIAL:
            state.splice(action.payload, 1)
            return state;
            
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducer } from './reducers/tutorial.reducer';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      tutorial: reducer
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
_____________________________
```

err:-
Type '(state: Tutorial[] | undefined, action: Actions) => Tutorial[]' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<Tutorial[], Action>'.
Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'Actions'.
Property 'payload' is missing in type 'Action' but required in type 'RemoveTutorial'.ts(2322)
tutorial.actions.ts(19, 17): 'payload' is declared here.

Comment: I think the problem is here -> `action: TutorialActions.Actions`. How do you export actions?

Comment: i am new for @ngrx concepts...i have added one more file,tutorial.action.ts,could you please check it out